# Связь между сущностями в Drupal 8

Tags: drupal

Есть Drupal 8:

1. На созданной вручную странице, доступной для показа только админу, выводится таблица предприятий (с полями "Название предприятия", "URl-адрес"). Предприятия занесены в словарь таксономии (с дополнительным полем URl-адрес). Добавление предприятия происходит через форму, созданную через свой модуль. Таблица выводится стандартными средствами.
2. На созданной вручную странице, доступной для показа залогиненому пользователю, выводится таблица личных счетов (с полями "Предприятие", "Личный счет"). Тут он может добавить новый личный счет, выбрав предприятие, к которому относится. Форма добавления создана програмно, через свой модуль. Для хранения этих данных создана отдельная таблица в БД. Вывод таблицы тоже через свой модуль.

Что нужно сделать:

Админ хочет для каждого предприятия добавлять новости (одну или несколько). Потом эти новости как-то должен увидеть пользователь, причем новости того предприятия, у которого у него есть личный счет (например, в виде ссылки в его таблице в названии предприятия). Т.е., в таблице щелкает по названии предприя, и ему выводятся все новости. Щелкает по другому предприятию, выводять други новости.

Если нет готового решения, буду рад подсказке, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Страницы сделаны через Views (Представления)?

Comment: Да. Вопрос решился установкой модуля message_private